# 2018 Ford Fusion door chime won't turn off

Tags: ford

So i've had my fusion for a few months now, and this problem cropped up yesterday.

Normally when you put the car in park, and open the door if you still have the key in the ignition or the headlights on, a chime will play until you fix that. Well, last night it went off and I could not figure out why. My key is out of the ignition, all lights including interior lights off. the chime still plays until I shut the door or put the key back in. Normally it would be off in this scenario, even with the door open.

Anyone know why it would continue playing or how to fix it?

EDIT: Looked in owners manual, nothing there was helpful. still looking for a way to fix.

Comment: Hi and welcome.

Comment: Its a new car. Go to the dealer and ask them what is going on, preferrably ask the guy that sold it to you. Should be an easy, quick and free solution.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things come to mind which you can check:

1) is the indicator stalk left set to indicate a right or left turn - this may put "parking lights" on on that side...

2) is there a glove box or storage box light left on due to the door not being closed properly...

Comment: Also check the vehicle owners manual, the possible reasons for the chime are often listed there.

Comment: I tried this, neither worked.